# Android Searchview causing application to force close

Tags: java, android

thankyou in advance for looking at this pose. I am trying to filter my recyclerview using searchview and I watched a lot of tutorials in youtube and all of them is not working because when I input letter in searchbar the application is crashing. Before I insert the code I can type in searchbar and is not causing error. (The recyclerview is working well before inserting code to searchview)

**java code:**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class search extends AppCompatActivity implements SelectListener{

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<canFood> foods;
    foodSearchAdapter foodSearchAdapter;
    androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView searchView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        List<canFood> foods = new ArrayList<canFood>();

        foods.add(new canFood("Carrots", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Grapes and Raisins", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Salt", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Peanut Butter", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Eggs", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Salmon", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Chocolate", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Cheese", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Blueberries", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Popcorn", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Cashews", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Almonds", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Pineapple", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Onions", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Watermelon", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Bread", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Blackberries", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Avocado", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Corn", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Tomatoes", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Green Peas", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Coffee and Tea", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Apples", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Garlic", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Broccoli", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Chicken", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Sweet Potatoes", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Coconut", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Alcohol", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Pork", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Cinnamon", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Mango", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Honey", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Milk", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Turkey", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Rice", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Beef", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Lemons and Limes", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Bananas", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Strawberries", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Peanuts", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Mushrooms", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Potatoes", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Celery", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Cherries", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Shrimp", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Fish", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Ham", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Bug Spray and Sunscreen", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Ice cream", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Oatmeal", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Raw Yeast Dough", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Spicy Food", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Tobacco", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Oranges", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Pears", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Cucumber", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Fat Trimmings", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Bones", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Plums", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Raw Meat", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Raw Fish", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Sugary Foods", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Sugary Drinks", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Human Medicines", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Kitchen Pantry", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Candy", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Toothpaste", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Cocoa", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Human Vitamins", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Breath Fresheners", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Spoiled Foods", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Oily Foods", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Oily Foods", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Lettuce", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Spinach", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Soaps", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Yogurt", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Pasta", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Household Chemicals", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Pizza", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Laundry Supplies", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Lawn and Garden Supplies", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Pesticides", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Baking powder", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Baking soda", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Chicken Skin", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Chili", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Bathroom Cleaning Supplies", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Chives", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Gravy", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Ketchup", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Mustard", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Coke", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Xylitol", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Juice", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Pickles", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Olives", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Grilled Foods", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Pumpkin", R.drawable.ic_like));


        foodSearchAdapter = new foodSearchAdapter(this, foods, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(foodSearchAdapter);

        searchView = findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                filter(newText);
                return true;
            }
        });


    }



    private void filter(String newText) {
        List<canFood> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (canFood item : foods){
            if (item.getFoodname().toLowerCase().contains(newText.toLowerCase())){
                filteredList.add(item);
            }
        }
        foodSearchAdapter.filterList(filteredList);

    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClicked(canFood canFood) {
        Toast.makeText(this, canFood.getFoodname(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**xml code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".search">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="1800dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_view_bg"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:queryHint="Search Food Here ...">

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView>


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/searchView"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**adapter code:**

```
package com.example.dogapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class foodSearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<foodViewHolder> {


    Context context;
   List<canFood> foods;
   SelectListener listener;




    public foodSearchAdapter(Context context, List<canFood> foods, SelectListener listener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.foods = foods;
        this.listener = listener;
    }



    @NonNull
    @Override
    public foodViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new foodViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.food_view,parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull foodViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.nameView.setText(foods.get(position).getFoodname());
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(foods.get(position).getIcon());

        holder.relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listener.onItemClicked(foods.get(position));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return foods.size();
    }

    public void filterList(List<canFood> filteredList){
            foods = filteredList;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
    }




}
```

**viewholder code:**

```
package com.example.dogapplication;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class foodViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView imageView;
    TextView nameView;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;


    public foodViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        nameView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodname);
relativeLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_container);

    }
}
```

**crash log**

```
2023-01-02 17:37:34.027 5420-5420/com.example.dogapplication E/InputEventSender: Exception dispatching finished signal for seq=70
2023-01-02 17:37:34.027 5420-5420/com.example.dogapplication E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
2023-01-02 17:37:34.029 5420-5420/com.example.dogapplication E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.dogapplication.search.filter(search.java:158)
        at com.example.dogapplication.search.access$000(search.java:15)
        at com.example.dogapplication.search$1.onQueryTextChange(search.java:38)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.onTextChanged(SearchView.java:1198)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView$10.onTextChanged(SearchView.java:1736)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:10789)
        at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:10904)
        at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:13807)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1268)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:577)
        at androidx.emoji2.text.SpannableBuilder.replace(SpannableBuilder.java:315)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:508)
        at androidx.emoji2.text.SpannableBuilder.replace(SpannableBuilder.java:305)
        at androidx.emoji2.text.SpannableBuilder.replace(SpannableBuilder.java:49)
        at android.text.method.QwertyKeyListener.onKeyDown(QwertyKeyListener.java:228)
        at android.text.method.TextKeyListener.onKeyDown(TextKeyListener.java:141)
        at androidx.emoji2.viewsintegration.EmojiKeyListener.onKeyDown(EmojiKeyListener.java:58)
        at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:8557)
        at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:8331)
        at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.onKeyDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:862)
        at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2854)
        at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:14478)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1964)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1964)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1964)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1964)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1964)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1964)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1964)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1964)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1964)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1964)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:490)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1880)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:4156)
        at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.superDispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:124)
        at androidx.core.view.KeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEventDispatcher.java:86)
        at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:142)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:601)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:3106)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:404)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6278)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:6144)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5626)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5683)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5649)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5814)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5657)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5871)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5630)
2023-01-02 17:37:34.029 5420-5420/com.example.dogapplication E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5683)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5649)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5657)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5630)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5683)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5649)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5847)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6005)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:3158)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:2722)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:2713)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:3135)
        at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:154)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:161)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
2023-01-02 17:37:34.029 5420-5420/com.example.dogapplication D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2023-01-02 17:37:34.031 5420-5420/com.example.dogapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.dogapplication, PID: 5420
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.dogapplication.search.filter(search.java:158)
        at com.example.dogapplication.search.access$000(search.java:15)
        at com.example.dogapplication.search$1.onQueryTextChange(search.java:38)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.onTextChanged(SearchView.java:1198)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView$10.onTextChanged(SearchView.java:1736)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:10789)
        at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:10904)
        at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:13807)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1268)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:577)
        at androidx.emoji2.text.SpannableBuilder.replace(SpannableBuilder.java:315)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:508)
        at androidx.emoji2.text.SpannableBuilder.replace(SpannableBuilder.java:305)
        at androidx.emoji2.text.SpannableBuilder.replace(SpannableBuilder.java:49)
        at android.text.method.QwertyKeyListener.onKeyDown(QwertyKeyListener.java:228)
        at android.text.method.TextKeyListener.onKeyDown(TextKeyListener.java:141)
        at androidx.emoji2.viewsintegration.EmojiKeyListener.onKeyDown(EmojiKeyListener.java:58)
        at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:8557)
        at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:8331)
        at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.onKeyDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:862)
        at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2854)
        at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:14478)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1964)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1964)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1964)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1964)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1964)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1964)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1964)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1964)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1964)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1964)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:490)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1880)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:4156)
        at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.superDispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:124)
        at androidx.core.view.KeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEventDispatcher.java:86)
        at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:142)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:601)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:3106)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:404)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6278)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:6144)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5626)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5683)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5649)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5814)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5657)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5871)
2023-01-02 17:37:34.032 5420-5420/com.example.dogapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5630)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5683)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5649)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5657)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5630)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5683)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5649)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5847)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6005)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:3158)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:2722)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:2713)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:3135)
        at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:154)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:161)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

I tried watching different kind of tutorial for searchview and recyclerview but when I insert letter to filter the recycler view the error occurs.

Comment: Can you share the crash log?

Comment: oh my bad I added it now

Comment: Just make the `List<canFood> foods = new ArrayList<canFood>();` and `foods.add()` in the top of the `searchView = findViewById(R.id.searchView);`

Comment: still causing an error @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI

Comment: Your error log said that your foods list is `null`, try to move the whole `searchView` code below the foods list code

Comment: I moved it sir and it still causes error I will edit the code above and can you check if I did it right?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be found using the help of the crash log.
The first line there states that:

> 2023-01-02 17:37:34.029 5420-5420/com.example.dogapplication
> E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke
> interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a
> null object reference
> at com.example.dogapplication.search.filter(search.java:158)

If we look at the method, we will see:

```
   private void filter(String newText) {
        List<canFood> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (canFood item : foods){
            if (item.getFoodname().toLowerCase().contains(newText.toLowerCase())){
                filteredList.add(item);
            }
        }
        foodSearchAdapter.filterList(filteredList);

    }
```

**The crash comes from the fact that the foods list you want to iterate on is null.**
Why is it null? Because of this:

1. You are declaring it as a member variable at the beginning of your class

> public class search extends AppCompatActivity implements
> SelectListener{
> RecyclerView recyclerView;
> List foods;
> foodSearchAdapter foodSearchAdapter;
> androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView searchView;

2. But you are never giving it any value. The logic you have is setting a completely different foods list (local variable)

   List foods = new ArrayList();

Comment: so what should I do sir?

Comment: Initiate that list with the values you want in onCreate (instead of the local list).

Answer (score 0):

In `filter` method, you are iterating over the list that never defined.

So in `onCreate` method in  `search` class, initialize it first before adding data.

**How to do that,**

1. Initialise the global arrayList so that you can modify it.

```
List <canFood> foods = new ArrayList();
```

2. Remove below line from `onCreate` method,

```
List<canFood> foods = new ArrayList<canFood>();
```

And add below line in that place to avoid data duplication.

```
foods.clear()
```

Now you are done. Your code will run.

**Additional notes**

Whenever you create custom class, name it capitalised to avoid conflicts with variables.
i.e, Your model class `canFood` should be named as `CanFood`
Your adapter class `foodSearchAdapter` should be named as `FoodSearchAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class search extends AppCompatActivity implements SelectListener{

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<canFood> foods =  new ArrayList() ;
    foodSearchAdapter foodSearchAdapter;
    androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView searchView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        
        foods.add(new canFood("Carrots", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Grapes and Raisins", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Salt", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Peanut Butter", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Eggs", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Salmon", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Chocolate", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Cheese", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Blueberries", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Popcorn", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Cashews", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Almonds", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Pineapple", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Onions", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Watermelon", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Bread", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Blackberries", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Avocado", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Corn", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Tomatoes", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Green Peas", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Coffee and Tea", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Apples", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Garlic", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Broccoli", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Chicken", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Sweet Potatoes", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Coconut", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Alcohol", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Pork", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Cinnamon", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Mango", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Honey", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Milk", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Turkey", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Rice", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Beef", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Lemons and Limes", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Bananas", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Strawberries", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Peanuts", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Mushrooms", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Potatoes", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Celery", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Cherries", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Shrimp", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Fish", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Ham", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Bug Spray and Sunscreen", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Ice cream", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Oatmeal", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Raw Yeast Dough", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Spicy Food", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Tobacco", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Oranges", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Pears", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Cucumber", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Fat Trimmings", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Bones", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Plums", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Raw Meat", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Raw Fish", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Sugary Foods", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Sugary Drinks", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Human Medicines", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Kitchen Pantry", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Candy", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Toothpaste", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Cocoa", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Human Vitamins", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Breath Fresheners", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Spoiled Foods", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Oily Foods", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Oily Foods", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Lettuce", R.drawable.ic_like));
        foods.add(new canFood("Spinach", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Soaps", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Yogurt", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Pasta", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Household Chemicals", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Pizza", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Laundry Supplies", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Lawn and Garden Supplies", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Pesticides", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Baking powder", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Baking soda", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Chicken Skin", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Chili", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Bathroom Cleaning Supplies", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Chives", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Gravy", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Ketchup", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Mustard", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Coke", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Xylitol", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Juice", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Pickles", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Olives", R.drawable.ic_warn));
        foods.add(new canFood("Grilled Foods", R.drawable.ic_limit));
        foods.add(new canFood("Pumpkin", R.drawable.ic_like));


        foodSearchAdapter = new foodSearchAdapter(this, foods, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(foodSearchAdapter);

        searchView = findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                filter(newText);
                return true;
            }
        });


    }



    private void filter(String newText) {
        List<canFood> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (canFood item : foods){
            if (item.getFoodname().toLowerCase().contains(newText.toLowerCase())){
                filteredList.add(item);
            }
        }
        foodSearchAdapter.filterList(filteredList);

    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClicked(canFood canFood) {
        Toast.makeText(this, canFood.getFoodname(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```